# Floating Video Player in android?

Tags: android, media-player, multitasking, http-live-streaming

I have added the Vitamio player in my android application. And it Works fine. Is there any method in Vitamio or any other player so that I can make the player floating over other apps and resizable like [this](http://androidspin.com/2013/02/28/app-of-the-week-popcorn-floating-video-player/) one?

Comment: That is a pop up, I reckon. You open a custom pop up with a VideoView and set its setCancelable to false. Pass your url to it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

The technique described [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124153/how-to-add-a-floating-view-to-android-window-manager-and-listen-to-system-hardwa) can be used to create these types of floating windows. There is also the excellent [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) library, given as one of the answers in that post, that implements this with a nice API.

Comment: Could you post some relevant content from your link?