# How to Make Activity Which Appear on Half Screen?

Tags: android, xml

i want to make an activity which appears on half screen **(JUST LIKE DIALOG BOX BUT NOT DIALOG BOX)** i want to add some text,switch buttons and labels on it ?

i tried Dialog Boxes but it does not satisfy me so now i want to resize activity. **HELP**

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is insane xD But you can use floating window for such behaviour.

Comment: @berserk will u please guide me that ho can i do it ? because i am going to experiment it first time. i shall be very thankful to u

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124153/how-to-add-a-floating-view-to-android-window-manager-and-listen-to-system-hardwa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy. Just use fragments! With fragments, you will have complete control of size and location of everything. See my example

**Here is my main xml.** This is two separate fragments. Each takes up about a quarter of the screen.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="12dp">

<fragment
    android:name="com.diamond.home.fragments.TopFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <!-----here, add the rest of your xml for your main activity -------->
```

Your main activity that will display these fragments will not need to do anything to display your fragments because your XML will already call the fragments in for you. NOTE: if you want to display the fragment only at certain times, you can reference the `fragment` from the xml, and set the visibility to GONE. Then when you need it, set it to VISIBLE.

**Then, Create fragment classes like so:**

```
 public class TopFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments_top, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   //do your stuff for your fragment here


}
```

So you will also need to create another xml layout for your top-fragment. In that, you can add buttons, text views or what have you. Hope this helps. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: if i want to do show a fragment dialog from activity class what should i have to o , i never experienced fragments,

Comment: Just make your main activity (that shows the dialog) extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity. Take a look at these tutorials. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html.

Comment: There a two ways, that I can think of, that you might go about doing it. The way I listed above, or instead of a `<fragment` layout use a `<Frame` layout. Set it's attributes to whatever you like. In your case, alignParentTop, and half whatever for height. fill parent for width. Then when you show it. Set the frame layout to visible, then do a FragmentTransaction on that Frame Layout to the Fragment that is the dialog.

Comment: i cant mark it because i have only 1 reputation and it require 15 to mark an answer , can u please vote my question it will help me to increase  reputation

Comment: Ah, ok. Well accept it when you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Ok i will Accept it but if u can increase my reputation i will do it now **thanks**

Comment: i am feeling so much dificulty in making fragment dialog can u please help me if i snd you my code via email can u do some thing for me?